# Error reading body: System.Xml.XmlException: '���Z��m' contains invalid UTF8 bytes

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, utf-8, wcf-binding

I am developing the one WCF service, In which I create the custom MessageFormatter using the `IDispatchMessageFormatter`.

Here somehow I editing the request message coming from the client before the deserialize it.

```
public void DeserializeRequest(Message message, object[] parameters)
{
    try
    {
        RequestMessage objRequestMessage = new RequestMessage(message);
        Message objNewMessage = objRequestMessage.RecreateMessage();
        this.objMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(objNewMessage, parameters);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

It working fine with the all clients, but for one of the client is does not work.

When the client send the request and `DeserializeRequest` method is called, in the argument of the `DeserializeRequest` there is the object of the `Message` class called `message`.

In Which the original request is not come, but it gives me the following message.

> {... Error reading body: System.Xml.XmlException: '���Z��m' contains
>   invalid UTF8 bytes. ...}

It gives the above message even before the my code is executed, even the the first line of the `DeserializeRequest` method is not executed.

**I think it must be the mismatch of the encoding types used by the client and the server.**

**Service:**

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://my-wcf.com/WepAPI")]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IWWRSPFWebAPIMFPService
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "http://my-wcf.com/WepAPI#SayHello")]
    [CMessageBehavior]
    HelloReponse SayHello(HelloRequest helloRequest);
}
```

**app.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>  
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>    
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>          
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>    
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It looks like it is compressed. Went something wrong with http-compression?

Comment: @rene Thanks for the reply. But I does not understand what are you saying. Please, can you help me to solve this problem ?